Is proper time still maximized with different metric signature?
A free particle moving from event $a$ to event $b$, which is timelike connected to $a$, on spacetime follows geodesics. In most cases it is a path that minimizes this integral
$$S=\int_a^b ds=\int_a^b \sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu}.\tag{1}$$
As a consequence of minimizing this integral, proper time of the particle is maximized
$$\tau_{ab}=\int_a^bd\tau=\int_a^b\sqrt{\frac{-ds^2}{c^2}}.\tag{2}$$
because of negative sign before $ds^2$. However, this result is based on the fact that the metric signature is $(-,+,+,+)$. I wonder what happens when the metric signature is $(+,-,-,-)$. Is proper time still maximized in this case?
I read this answer and it didn't address my doubt.

The "proof" of the fact that proper time maximize the distance in that answer is wrong. There is an elementary proof of the mentioned fact in an answer of mine, for Minkowski spacetime. The general result valid for Lorentzian manifod (in geodesically convex neighborhoods)  is a consequence of the Minkowskian case and a subtle result called Gauss lemma.

In these lecture notes of mine https://moretti.maths.unitn.it/manifolds.pdf there is a proof of that fact at the end of section 7.2.3.

Comment to the post (v2): Eqs. (1) & (2) seems to apply opposite signature conventions.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/529574/

TL;DR: The two signature conventions describe one and the same physical situation$^1$.

In formulas,
$$ \pm c^2(d\tau)^2~=~(ds)^2~=~g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\mu}, \tag{A}$$
if the Minkowski signature is $(\pm,\mp,\mp,\mp)$, respectively.

So a finite lapse of proper time is
$$ \tau~=~\frac{1}{c}\int \sqrt{\pm g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\mu}}.\tag{B}$$

Note that the tangents of a worldline/curve should be everywhere non-spacelike in order to make the argument of the square root non-negative.

The geodesics are given by stationary curves of the functional (B).

That the proper time (B) is maximized in Minkowski space is proven in e.g. this & this Phys.SE posts.

NB: There is no timelike curve that minimizes the proper time (B), cf. e.g. this Phys.SE post.



$^1$ We assume that OP is not considering a spacetime with 1 space and 3 time directions!

In other news one notes that $\mathrm{d}\tau$ and $\mathrm{d}t$ have the same sign, while the spatial 1-forms have whatever sign the temporal forms don’t have.

Thank you. So using Minkowski metric as an example, both signatures results in the same integral: $\Delta\tau=\frac1c\int\sqrt{c^2dt^2-dx^2-dy^2-dz^2}$. Now I wonder if both actions $S=\frac1c\int\sqrt{c^2dt^2-dx^2-dy^2-dz^2}$ and $S=\frac1c\int\sqrt{-c^2dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}$ results in the same Euler-Lagrange equations. If so, then the solution to the equation will maximize the former while minimizing the latter?

The latter square root action is ill-posed since it is ill-defined on timelike worldlines.

The physics cannot change!
The $g_{\mu\nu}$ has to encode spacetime curvature when there is curvature, and so it is convenient to still define the flat spacetime $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ which is the diagonal of the metric signature, i.e. constants of $\pm1$ or $0$ as appropriate for your spacetime.
Then the correct metric-signature-independent definition of proper time is
$$c\,\mathrm d\tau=\sqrt{\eta_{tt}\,\mathrm ds^2}$$
Personally, I prefer to write $\eta^{tt}$ just to not have so many subscripts, but that is manifestly the same thing.
